# Sign In / Sign Out is not working in topmenu.phtml Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, magento2.4, customer-login

I am trying to add sign-in in the mobile menu, so I had designed the menu according to that but when in default I had given the Sign In link once he signed in I will show the My Account link. I used the Customer View Model to check the Customer logged in or not, for me after sign in also for me sign in itself showing, so I cleared the cache at backed and checked it changed to My Account after that I logged out means it still shows My Account. I had declared the block as non-cacheable but still, I am facing this problem can any guide show the menu. I used the below code to check the Customer is logged or not

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

<?php if($customerSession->isLoggedIn() == 1): ?>
    <p>Huray, you're logged in!</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(!$isCustomerLoggedIn): ?>
    <p>Hey, you're not logged in!</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try the below solution,**

```
 <li data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
        <!-- ko if: customer().fullname  -->
    
            <p>Huray, you're logged in!</p>
    
        <!-- /ko -->
        
        <!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname  -->
    
            <p>Hey, you're not logged in!</p>
    
        <!-- /ko -->
   </li>
        
        
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
            {
                "*": {
                    "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                        "components": {
                            "customer": {
                                "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            </script>
```